# Lotus Notes Client and designer installation

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I had installed my Lotus Notes client on my desktop on D drive, everything was working well, suddenly it got crashed and I had to uninstall Lotus Notes completely.

Now when I tried to install it once again, it takes previous path of lotus notes which is D drive and I can not change it at all, the Browse button on installation on installation dialog box becomes grayed out.

I want to install it now in C drive instead of D drive where it was previously installed.

Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the instructions on this page to clean your previous installation. and then proceed again.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245159

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something went wrong during un-installation process and windows reg was not clean properly.

Basically you may need to clean windows register (regedit.exe).

Try to check following places to see if there is a PATH/DATAPATH pointing to the notes client you uninstalled (and if you find them - just delete it)

1. Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\IBM\Notes\Installer

or

2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Lotus\Notes